# Is it right, Pro-verb refers to a verb not a verb phrase?

Tags: verbs

In the sentence below, 'do' refers to 'sense the environment' ,which is evident. But can 'do' refer to only a verb 'sense'?

Share what you think about this, and please explain why it is or isn't okay.

> It is lazy and dangerous for the ecologist to assume that all other organisms sense the environment in the way we do.

Answer (score 2):

From the "pro-verb" entry [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pro-verb), which is worth reading:

> In linguistics, a pro-verb is a verb or partial phrase that substitutes for a contextually recognizable verb phrase (via a process known as grammatical gapping), obviating the need to repeat an antecedent verb phrase. A pro-verb is a type of anaphora that falls within the general group of word classes called pro-forms.

A verb phrase is a clause or sentence.

The pro-verb works in the same way as a **pro**noun which may substitute for a noun phrase. The NP may be complex or may be a single word:

**The car that he had bought from his brother** was not a bargain: **it** required a new engine.

**Weather** had eroded the sandstone and **it** had also damaged the roof.

The same applies to a pro-verb - its referent can be a verb or a verb clause.

Comment: @Lambie I am answering the **title** question, which is a generality. The OP should be able to resolve the specific point himself with the information provided. As it happens, *do* = "sense the environment."

Comment: That's one of the worst Wikipedia pages I've ever read. Some of the sentences just drop off half-way through.

Answer (score 0):

They play piano better than I **do**. [avoids repeating play piano]

He likes cake more than I **do**. [avoids repeating like cake]

I love sports more than he **does**. [avoids repeating love sports].

Wikipedia definition of a pro-verb:

In linguistics, a pro-verb is a verb or partial phrase that substitutes for a contextually recognizable verb phrase (via a process known as grammatical gapping), obviating the need to repeat an antecedent verb phrase.[1] A pro-verb is a type of anaphora that falls within the general group of word classes called pro-forms.

He made me ask the question. So I *did.* [ask the question]
Would you please be quiet? Answer: Yes, I *might*.
Why are you doing the washing-up? Answer: Because I *can*.

Sometimes a pro-verb occurs in a conversation and the substitution is for a main verb used by the other speaker.